# jQuery expander on collapse

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jQuery expander](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander) for a read more-read less type situation and it's working fine. I'd like to scroll the user to the headline of the article after they click read less. I'm trying to figure out the code but I'm not too familiar with jQuery.

```
$('.expand_please').expander({
  slicePoint: 1000,
  widow: 2,
  expandEffect: 'show',
  userCollapseText: 'Read less',
  expandText: 'Read more',
  onCollapse: $(this).closest('h2').scroll()
});
```

**EDIT:** Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="row keyline" id="show_article1">
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 1em;">TITLE</h2>
  <div class="link_article" style="display: none;"><a href="/share/thomas/more/18" data-remote="true">READ MORE</a></div>
  <div class="fivecol">
    <img alt="thumbnail" class="thumbnail" src="/system/thumb.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="sevencol last expand_please marginer"><div class="summary" style="display: none;">
  ARTICLE BODY TEXT
  <span class="read-less"><a href="#">Read less</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Believe that onCollapse wants a function to call when the expander collapses.  You are also looking for jQuery's .scrollTop method not .scroll.  .scroll attaches a handler to the scroll event.
Try the following

```
$('.expand_please').expander({
    slicePoint: 1000,
    widow: 2,
    expandEffect: 'show',
    userCollapseText: 'Read less',
    expandText: 'Read more',
    onCollapse: function () {
        $('body').scrollTop($(this).closest('h2').offset().top);
    }
});
```

UPDATE:  .closest() will not work because it looks through ancestors of the matched set of elements.  In the HTML provided you are actually trying to select a sibling, e.g.

```
$(this).siblings('h2').first().offset().top
```

Comment: Promising! That does get an error, though, which I don't know how to interpret: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`.

Comment: The argument of "scrollTop" needs to be the position in px you want the page to scroll to.  That error means "$(this).closest('h2')" isn't returning any elements.  What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I didn't realise they were siblings before simplifying that HTML code.

Answer (score 3):

To scroll to the element in question, you simply need to get its `offset().top` value, and pass that value to the `animate()` method.

It'd look something like this:

```
$('.expand_please').expander({
      slicePoint: 1000,
      widow: 2,
      expandEffect: 'show',
      userCollapseText: 'Read less',
      expandText: 'Read more',
      onCollapse: function(){
        var amount = $(this).siblings('h2:first').offset().top;
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop : amount},800);

      }
});
```

The above method will obviously `animate` the scroll, which is a nice touch, but should you just want something more basic, you can use `element.scrollIntoView(true);`<sup>1</sup>

In your case, that would be:

```
...
onCollapse: function(){
    // pass true to align with top of scroll area
    // pass false to align with bottom of scroll area
    $(this).siblings('h2:first').scrollIntoView(true)
}
...
```

> <sup>1</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: This returns the same error as @jwags' solution, which was this: `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated my answer for reference, using `h2:first` (which is how I prefer to do it) instead of `first()` — same result, different approach.